# Android Studio - differences between debug and release builds

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

As the title says.... I'm trying to understand any possible differences between the "debug" and "release" build variants of my Android app **in addition** to those specified in the build.gradle file.

The reason for asking is that I'm trying to pin down some odd things that are happening when I build my Android app as a release build rather than a debug one, and I'm wondering what may be happening behind the scenes that I don't know about.

Here's the current version of the buildTypes section of build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        // Disable Proguard altogether, hopefully:
        minifyEnabled false
        // getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Beside this lot, is there anything done automatically in the release build by Android Studio? I'm using Android Studio version 2.2.3.

ASIDE 1 - Before anyone says that I shouldn't have `debuggable true` in a release build, I know that - I'm just trying to make the two builds identical in every respect so that I can pin down the weird things that are happening.

ASIDE 2: I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621766), and it doesn't address my one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell more about the "Weird" things that are happening?

Comment: @KushalSharma Sure, [here's a question I asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124079) for example. This isn't what I'm asking now, though - I just want to understand the build process better.